# MVC Model Validation Programmatic Registration support

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, attributes, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

Today (15th Jan 2010) Scott blogged about the ASP.NET MVC2 model-validation

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Anyone knows how can someone add validation rules at runtime programmatically ?

"Programmatic Registration" is a similar functionality supported by [ValidationAspects](http://www.codeplex.com/ValidationAspects)

```
// register lambda syntax validation functions
typeof(User).GetProperty("Name").AddValidation<string>((name, context) => 
  { if (!Exists(name)) { throw new ValidationException("Username is unknown"); } } );

// register validation factories (classes)
typeof(User).GetProperty("Name").AddValidation(new [] { new NotNullOrEmpty()} );

// don't like strings?
TypeOf<User>.Property(user => user.Name).AddValidation(new [] { new NotNullOrEmpty()} );
```

Comment: related: http://blogs.msdn.com/marcinon/archive/2008/05/22/dynamic-data-samples-custom-metadata-providers.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide custom metadata you'll have to implement the abstract class ModelMetadataProvider and register it inside your global.asax:

```
           ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new ConventionMetadataProvider();
```

This isn't adding validation attributes at runtime.  Your simply providing ALL the validation information into the ModelMetadata classes which are then read by the HTML.EditorFor bits.

Comment: You mean we can't add validation attributes at runtime with default functionality?

Can you elaborate please :)

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are created at compile-time, not run-time.  They cannot be changed after compile-time.

There are several run-time validation options, however.  My favorite is [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).  You create validation classes that execute at run-time.  You are more or less limited to only static data, and data from the model, however.